# How to deal with right zeros in a string to decimal conversion?

Tags: c#, .net

in my website i need to read data from a XML, and some of these datas are decimal values.
Sometimes the value comes correct: `1` or `72,59`and sometimes the value comes like `1.0000` or `72,590000`, how is the best way to convert it to the right format:

ps: I need a string value.

Thanks!

Comment: @phoog I Tried string.Format("{0:F}","1.00000"); and it not work.Outputs the same string

Comment: That's because you're passing a string into the function.  Numeric formatting only works on numeric data types.  Convert the value to a decimal first and then format it.

Answer (score 2):

What format are you wanting them to go to, specifically? How many decimals, etc?

If you want always 2 decimals, try a standard numeric formatting such as:

```
decimal value = 123.456;
Console.WriteLine("Your account balance is {0:F}.", value);
```

See [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dwhawy9k%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) MSDN example for other common numeric formatting techniques.

Comment: i tried string.Format("{0:F}", "1.0000")) , but it generates an error message saing that argument is Not IFormatable

Comment: Weird, you should be able to use `string myval = string.Format("{0:F}", "1.0000");`   to get a nice 2 decimal answer to that. Whats the whole line you are using for that call?

Comment: You may also want to try the following:

`decimal value = 123.456m;
string myVal = value.ToString("F");`

Comment: the resharper show me this alert, but when i run, the string.Format() function returns the same thing: 1.0000

Comment: See phoog's comment in your original question, you are passing in a string "1.0000", and it is unable to format this into a number because it is a string. You must first get it into a number (float, double, etc.) format, then pass it to format or .ToString("F");

Answer (score 1):

You write that you tried

```
string.Format("{0:F}","1.00000");
```

The problem with this is that you're passing a `string` into the function.  Numeric formatting only works on numeric data types.  Convert the value to a decimal first and then format it.

Try this

```
public string ReformatDecimalString(string input)
{
    const string formatString = //something
    var decimalValue = decimal.Parse(input);
    return decimalValue.ToString(formatString);
}
```

When you are formatting a single numeric value, it's slightly more efficient to use `x.ToString(formatString)` than `string.Format(formatString, x)`.  But note that the specific format string will be different in the two cases.

If your input data has decimal points (not commas) and your computer's culture uses decimal commas, you ought to be able to parse the value correctly by using CultureInfo.InvariantCulture:

```
var decimalValue = decimal.Parse(input, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Comment: This will work, but for completeness it might be nice if you flesh out your comment a bit to correct the OP's confusion about string.Format with strings versus numbers.

Comment: (in this answer, I mean)

Comment: @phoog i tried it and it works, but the result i get is 100000,00, the problem is that the number i get in the xml wich is 1.0000 should be 1. Its a xml value problem i think

Comment: @phoog and i tried to convert this 12.3200000 and i get this: 12.3200000,00

Comment: @ggui your sample xml values have mixed decimal points/decimal commas.  If the parse method is expecting a decimal comma with a period thousand separator, and you send it "1.0000", it will parse it as "10000".

Comment: @phoog i would like to get 12.32 for the 12.3200000 string. Understand?

Comment: @phoog and if i have a value like 78.70 , how can i format it to get 78.7 ? or to get 78.7 to 78.70?

Comment: @ggui see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dwhawy9k(v=vs.110).aspx (for standard format strings) and http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0c899ak8(v=vs.110).aspx (for custom format strings)

Answer (score 0):

If I'm reading your answer correctly, you're trying to convert Integer values you pull from an XML file into string values ***without trailing zeroes*** ("ps: I need a string value.")

this code:

```
decimal test = 20.000000m
test.ToString("G29");
```

might do what you want